# Indent each yasnippet line according to major mode

Tags: indentation, yasnippet

I want to use yasnippets to generate control flow statements in Lua.

```lua
-- a control flow statement in Lua
if foo then
   return "foo"
elseif bar then
   return "bar"
else 
   return "baz"
end
```

First I make a yasnippet for `if`.

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: if
# key: if
# binding: direct-keybinding
# --
if $1 then
  $0
end
```

No problem. Now I make a yasnippet for `elseif`

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: elseif
# key: elseif
# binding: direct-keybinding
# --
elseif $1 then
  $0
```

...and one for `else`.

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: else
# key: else
# binding: direct-keybinding
# --
else
  $0
```

However, using these snippets to generate the target control flow statement yields the following:

```lua
-- a misformatted control flow statement in Lua
if foo then
   return "foo"
   elseif bar then
     return "bar"
     else 
       return "baz"
end
```

I want to have the statements automatically align themselves correctly, just as if I pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd> on each line. `yas-indent-line` is already set to the default value of `'auto`, and of course setting it to `'fixed` is not the solution. I could accomplish the reindentation by customizing `yas-after-exit-snippet-hook`, but that seems too heavyweight. Is there an option in yasnippets to automatically indent each line according to the mode's default indentation of the line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there an option in yasnippets to automatically indent each line according to the mode's default indentation of the line?

This is what setting `yas-indent-line` to `'auto` is for, except that you also want to set `yas-also-auto-indent-first-line` to `t`. I guess it defaults to `nil` because it causes problems in some cases.